# Reverse order a for each on a array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have picked some code up another developer built. Poorly documented and not even sure where the api connection to the real estate listings. Anyway to the point, one of the pages on the site shows business listings in oldest to newest. I want to change that order.

This piece of code cycles through the properties to list these is like so:

```
foreach ( $properties->Listings as $property )
```

How can I reverse the order on this list?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `array_reverse()` function. So that:

```
array_reverse($properties->Listings)
```

You even don't need to use foreach.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php